# Error Code: 1064 SQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following query and getting error.
Please suggest me where i am doing mistake.
Thanks in advance...

```
CREATE TABLE users 

(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   username char varying(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   password character varying(100) NOT NULL, 
   group_id text,
   created timestamp,
   modified timestamp
   );
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html. Its `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 3):

try

```
CREATE TABLE users9
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    username char varying(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    group_id text,
    created timestamp,
    modified timestamp
);
```

A mere typo or two. See the manual page on [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Which is interesting. Because most people don;t create tables this way. At the end, one can execute `show create table users9` to show

```
CREATE TABLE `users9` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` text,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Showing the **schema.**

Which helps those that try to debug your programming questions that follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AUTO_INCREMENT instead of AUTOINCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
username char varying(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password character varying(100) NOT NULL,
group_id text,
created timestamp,
modified timestamp
);
```

See the **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adb284)**

Comment: Rahul@ while executing the below two lines in one of my SQL query i am getting error. 

created timestamp without time zone,

 modified timestamp without time zone

Comment: @NeerajPandey:- There is nothing like `without time zone` in MYSQL. Your syntax is wrong. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NeerajPandey:- See the manual of [TimeStamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html). It says: `MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)`